# How to fix int is not iterable in python?

Tags: python, string, integer

I input pesan in hexadecimal. For example e = 5, n = 221, and pesan = 1e. Then pesan will convert to decimal and decrypt it. The result (in decimal) will convert to hexadecimal again. But i got error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

How to solve it? Here's the code

```
def mod(x,y):
    if (x < y):
        return x
    else:
        c = x % y
        return c

def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    decimal_number = int(hex_str, 16)
    return decimal_number
                 
def decimal_to_hex(decimal_str):
    decimal_number = int(decimal_str, 10)
    hex_number = hex(decimal_number)[2:]
    return hex_number

def decrypt(m):
    plainDecimal=[]
    for i in m:
        cipherElement=mod(int(i)**e,n)
        plainDecimal.append(cipherElement)
    return plainDecimal

e = int(input('Input e: '))
n = int(input('Input n: '))
pesan = input('Input message: ' )
decimalp = hex_to_decimal(pesan) #Convert hex to decimal
plain = decrypt(decimalp)
ListToStr2 = ''.join([str(x) for x in plain])
decimal1 = decimal_to_hex(ListToStr2) #Convert decimal to hex
print("Dekripsi Tanda Tangan Digital (Heksadesimal): ", decimal1)
```

Comment: Looks like you're expecting `m` to be a string, but it's an integer instead.

Comment: What is ```hex_to_decimal``` or ```decimal-to_hex```? I cannot run the code

Comment: i've update the question

Comment: Also, what is ```mode```. Can you please provide that to?

Comment: i've update it.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you gave the decimalp value was an int, I now changed decimalp value using the str() function into string. The code should work now perfectly. The corrected code is given below;

```
def mod(x,y):
    if (x < y):
        return x
    else:
        c = x % y
        return c

def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    decimal_number = int(hex_str, 16)
    return decimal_number
                 
def decimal_to_hex(decimal_str):
    decimal_number = int(decimal_str, 10)
    hex_number = hex(decimal_number)[2:]
    return hex_number

def decrypt(m):
    plainDecimal=[]
    for i in m:
        cipherElement=mod(int(i)**e,n)
        plainDecimal.append(cipherElement)
    return plainDecimal

e = int(input('Input e: '))
n = int(input('Input n: '))
pesan = input('Input message: ' )
decimalp = str(hex_to_decimal(pesan)) #Convert hex to decimal
plain = decrypt(decimalp)
ListToStr2 = ''.join([str(x) for x in plain])
decimal1 = decimal_to_hex(ListToStr2) #Convert decimal to hex
print("Dekripsi Tanda Tangan Digital (Heksadesimal): ", decimal1)
```

Comment: looks like it decrypt one by one element in decimalp, so i got decimal1 = 1ea6fbaa612f328c9c711efe5692e6111d038279cb246c799165d20297b.  The result must be a6 for e = 5, n = 221, and pesan = 1e

Comment: Hey, Check now. I have edited my answer, The code would work properly now .

Comment: I've tried this too before. but I'm confused. why is the result dc instead of a6?

Answer (score 0):

i've solved this. Here's the code

```
def mod(x,y):
    if (x < y):
        return x
    else:
        c = x % y
        return c

def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    decimal_number = int(hex_str, 16)
    return decimal_number
                 
def decimal_to_hex(decimal_str):
    decimal_number = int(decimal_str, 10)
    hex_number = hex(decimal_number)[2:]
    return hex_number

def decrypt(m):
    m_str = str(m)
    decimalList =[int(m_str)]
    plainDecimal=[]
    for i in decimalList:
        cipherElement = mod(int(i)**e,n)
        plainDecimal.append(cipherElement)
    return plainDecimal

e = int(input('Input e: '))
n = int(input('Input n: '))
pesan = input('Input message: ' )
decimalp = str(hex_to_decimal(pesan)) #Convert hex to decimal
plain = decrypt(decimalp)
ListToStr2 = ''.join([str(x) for x in plain])
decimal1 = decimal_to_hex(ListToStr2) #Convert decimal to hex
print("Dekripsi Tanda Tangan Digital (Heksadesimal): ", decimal1)
```